# Where can I learn about how to represent liquids mathematically for an HTML5 canvas?

Tags: algorithm, html, canvas

I would like to learn how to represent liquid (water) in 2d and/or 3d mathematically to create a simulation using the HTML5 canvas. Any resources for this and/or representing other real-world materials in 2d or 3d mathematically?

Comment: A search term you might want to use is "fluid dynamics".

Comment: Or "physics engine" for the other materials

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is called [Particle Systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_system)

[Here](http://www.plunk.org/~trina/thesis/html/thesis_ch2.html) is a technique to model fluids and it includes an [implementation](http://www.plunk.org/~trina/thesis/html/thesis_ch3.html)

You can use a physics engine like [Box2D](http://box2d-js.sourceforge.net/) for javascript to create thousands of small circles or squares to simulate a fluid but I dont know if this is the way to go since you may face performance issues with this approach.

Comment: this is a great vid tut (but voice is in korean) http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v8ikTvQWfoc

Comment: Particle systems are not so good for fluids which in general are not compressible.

Comment: @Vovanium could you provide references about fluids simulation?

Comment: I've given some links to wikipedia in my answer to question above. I do not remember references now but will try to update my answer when i wind some. Circulation field is a common way for simulating fluid flows. Altough particle systems are used in some cases too (in case of turbulence/cavitation for example). My thought is that particle system would be so hard to compute in author case.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the best (simple) mathematic representation of non-compressible fluids flow (one of which is water) is using *[finite element method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_element_method)* over *[circulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulation_%28fluid_dynamics%29) field*.

In simple case finite elememt method could deal with rectangular grid.

But in more complex cases (turbulence, cavitation, fluid/gas interaction) there may need to be used another methods, like particle systems or other types of fields.

Also there may be combination of methods: FEM simulates fulid itelf and particle system visualises it (simulating dust of small particles floating in fluid).

Answer (score 0):

GPU Gems had a [chapter](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems/gpugems_ch02.html) on this. Might be a bit compute-intensive for HTML though.